# CBitmap::Setbitmap not working on windows xp?

Tags: mfc, windows-xp

CBitmap::Setbitmap not working with windows xp. Actually ,I am using windows7 operating system and I had a dialog application where I am loading bitmap on to the button using CBitmap::Setbitmap.

When I ran my application on windows xp machine I am not getting bitmaps I had loaded on the buttons.

This is how I am loading and setting the bitmap,

```
CButton *pMyButton = (CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_ADD_BTN);
BitmapStd.LoadBitmap(IDB_STANDARD_IDEAL_BMP);  
HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)BitmapStd.GetSafeHandle();
pMyButton->SetBitmap(hBitmap);
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?If possible please explain me with an example.

Comment: Please show the exact code you are using. Without it we cannot help.

Comment: As you told I had edited my original post.Please have a look at that and kindly let me know a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pierre Fournier suggested modified my code for loading a BITMAP and it is as follows.

In order to load a bitmap on a button on any operating system this is to be done,

```
CButton *pMyButton = reinterpret_cast<CButton*>GetDlgItem(IDC_MY_BUTTON);
HANDLE handle = LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(bitmpa.dll), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_MY_BMP),
                          IMAGE_BITMAP, 64, 64, 0);
HBITMAP hBmp = static_cast<HBITMAP >(handle);
SendMessage(pMyButton->GetSafeHwnd(), BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBmp );

DeleteObject(hBmp);//Deletes the attached Windows GDI object from memory by freeing all system //storage associated with the Windows GDI object.
```

It is working fine for me as I tested only on few operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it in Win32

```
HWND ctrl = GetDlgItem(m_hWnd, IDC_BUTTON_PREVIOUS);
HANDLE handle = LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_BLUELEFT),
                          IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, 0);
HICON m_iconPrevious = static_cast<HICON>(handle);
SendMessage(ctrl, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_ICON, (LPARAM)m_iconPrevious);
```

Be sure to call      DestroyIcon() when you're done.

Comment: I want load a bitmap not an icon ,I understood what you told and it's pretty good ,my doubt is if I  load a bitmap then how do I destroy that object HBITMAP in my case.I think there is no API available for destroying bitmap.Can you please let me know how can I do that.Instead of IMAGE_ICON I placed IMAGE_BITMAP and In the place of HICON placed HBITMAP .So,my problem is how do I destroy that.

Comment: You delete a HBITMAP using `DeleteObject()`